# Проверка фото на безопасность при приёме через JSON

Tags: php, json, безопасность, rest, img

Пишу прокладку для приёма данных в формате json и сохранения их на сайте. К исходным данным доступа нет, принимаю как есть. Сложность с фотографией лица юзера. Фото приходит мне в формате json через шифрование по bace64. Принять и расшифровать я могу, фото открывается. Проблема в том, что мне не приходят заголовки и я не представляю как проверить, что мне пришло именно фото. Упрощённо, приходит такая строка:

```
{"param":{"photo": "iVBORw0971jdm7cattmbDFlu8fJXggg=="}}
```

Длину сократил для примера. 
Не понимаю как обезопасить себя. При желании в строку можно будет запихнуть всё что угодно. htmlspetialchars() ведь не подойдёт? 
Подскажите, что почитать на эту тему. Может я не совсем понимаю, что происходит и решение проще чем я думаю?

Comment: Что-то я не понял проблемы, получилось раскодировать и открыть как картинку — значит картинка, не получилось — не картинка и фтопку, отчего как кого обезопасить-то?

Comment: [base64](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) это не шифрование.

Comment: @ andreymal Картинки визуально никто не оценивает. Открылась она или нет, как определить, на уровне кода?

Comment: Ну, методы открытия картинок в php по идее должны возвращать ошибку, если им подсунули не картинку. Imagick какой-нибудь

Comment: @andreymal благодарю, что-то я об этом совсем не подумал. Попробую использовать и этот подход.

Comment: @Ssssory Есть специальное расширение [FileInfo](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.fileinfo.php). Вам может подойти функция [finfo_buffer](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.finfo-buffer.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё что угодно в base64 запихнуть нельзя. 
Можете смело её `preg_match` (или как там в php) примерно такой регуляркой - `/^[A-Za-z0-9]+==$/`

**UP:**
такой регуляркой: `/^(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=)?$/`

Comment: Данная регулярка не пропустит почти любой base64 из-за отсутствия ещё двух символов и количества знаков `=` отличного от двух

Comment: @andreymal https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475074/regex-to-parse-or-validate-base64-data

Comment: Вот по ссылке, которую вы дали, регулярки правильные. А ваша регулярка неправильная

Comment: @andreymal кто-то хочет удочку, а кто то рыбку. Вы явно удочки не котируете

Comment: @Darth Если я правильно понял, переданный скрипт даст спецсимволы, которые великолепно экранируются, как и в обычных строках? Тоесть с изображением в base64 можно поступать так же как со строкой?

Comment: @Ssssory изображение, кодированное в base64 - это не просто строка, это строка в строго определённом формате. Проверить эту строку на соотвествие этому формату можно с помощью регулярного выражения из моего ответа